# Extend class attribute with Mixin

Tags: python

I want to write a Mixin who can extend eventual parent class atribute instead replace it. Example:

```
class Base(object):
    my_attr = ['foo', 'bar']

class MyMixin(object):
    my_attr = ['baz']

class MyClass(MyMixin, Base):
    pass

print(MyClass.my_attr)
```

> ['baz']

How write `MyMixin` to have `MyClass.my_attr` with `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` as value ?

Answer can be to do the merge in `MyClass`, but i want to know if it's possible to do it in **MyMixin**. Like with MetaClass or something else ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to do this on class attributes with a mixin, you'll have to use a custom metaclass AND put the mixin after `Base` in the mro (which means it won't override anything in the base class, just add to it):

```
class Base(object):
    my_attr = ['foo', 'bar']

class MyMixinBase(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, parents, attribs):
        my_attr = getattr(cls, "my_attr", None)
        if my_attr is None:
            cls.my_attr = ["baz"]
        elif "baz" not in my_attr:
            my_attr.append("baz")


class MyMixin(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMixinBase

class MyClass(Base, MyMixin):
    pass

print(MyClass.my_attr)
```

which makes for quite convoluted code... At this point, just using `MyMixinBase` as metaclass for `MyClass` would yield the same result:

```
class MyOtherClass(Base):
    __metaclass__ = MyMixinBase

print(MyOtherClass.my_attr)
```

and for such a use case, a class decorator works just fine:

```
def with_baz(cls):
    my_attr = getattr(cls, "my_attr", None)
    if my_attr is None:
        cls.my_attr = ["baz"]
    elif "baz" not in my_attr:
        my_attr.append("baz")
    return cls

@with_baz
class AnotherClass(Base):
    pass

print(AnotherClass.my_attr)
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly what i hoped.

Comment: @bux glad to be of any help - now (just out of curiousity) would you care sharing which of the three "solutions" solved your problem ?-)

Comment: I added python3 version to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base(object):
    my_attr = ['foo', 'bar']

class MyMixin(object):
    my_attr = ['baz']

class MyClass(MyMixin, Base):
    my_attr = MyMixin.my_attr + Base.my_attr


print(MyClass.my_attr)
```

> ['baz', 'foo', 'bar']

You will have to manually merge them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, since your second class doesn't access to the first one. One way is getting the `my_attr` within `my_calss` from each class and add them together. If you don't want to do this for any reason you can access to the `my_attr` of all bases and chain them:

```
In [20]: from itertools import chain

In [21]: list(chain.from_iterable(cls.my_attr for cls in MyClass.__bases__))
Out[21]: ['baz', 'foo', 'bar']
```